# Workflow email that is sent daily and totals up the days payments?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

My list has a view where it displays the SUM of the selected field. When filtered by todays date the sum shows me all totals for all payments against all regions in our business. This works great.
A user has asked me for this information to be sent in a daily email at the end of the day. 
I cannot figure out how to do this as the SUMs are calculated by the view and the filters within the view!? How do I even get this information in the Workflow email...the calculation action seems to limited.
Thanks

Comment: you can do that with JungleBell using repeater (dynamic block which takes info from sharepoint) http://www.enovapoint.com/blog/post/Customizing-SharePoint-Alerts-boost-Sales-Procedures

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom activity to execute an spquery. Sounds like that would be useful in a lot of instances.